# Drop down menu showing behind logo in ie 7 and 8

Tags: drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

My drop down menu (http://tornaia.com) shows up behind the logo in ie 7 and ie 8 (not in firefox, ie 9 or chrome).

Screen shot in ie7: (http://tornaia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Logo_menu_ie.jpg)

Screen shot in firefox, what it should look like: (http://tornaia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Logo_menu_firefox.jpg)

I have read that this could be caused by z-values, but I'm not quite sure how or where to change them. My best guesses would be in the `headere.php`: (http://pastebin.com/rTxzSNFx) or `methods.php`: (http://pastebin.com/tpD6MFuM).

Anyone who can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your logo a z-index of less than what your UL has which looked like 99 I believe.
Here is what you currently have

```
.logo-image {
  position: relative;
}
```

try

```
.logo-image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

the file you need to reference for editing can be found here http://tornaia.com/wp-content/themes/rumput-hijau/style.css

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried what you said, but it didn't work. I also tried to insert your code with other similar elements: `.site-title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.site-branding {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}` but it didn't work neither. By the way I found this in the same file: `.nav li.hover ul {
  left: 0;
  top: 2.5em;
  z-index: 99;
}` So I think you are right that the ul has z-index 99.

Comment: Try setting .logo-image z-index to -1 ... I updated the code above if you just want to copy and page